# Unable to get percentage from sql query

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to calculate the total scoring in percentage. Each question carry 12 marks. Below is my sql query from sqlite to get the percentage for the score. However, it does not show the correct calculation. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my query ?

```
select (sum(Score)/(count(Question))*12) *100 from Questions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `score` column type is `integer`, the math will be integer-based and you'll get 0.

Switch to floating-point math by casting one of the operands to `real`:

```
select (cast(sum(Score) as real)/(count(Question))*12) *100 from Questions
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select (sum(Score)/(count(Question)*12)) *100 from Questions
```

It looks like the placement of your brackets is making the order of operations happen in an order that you don't want.